# Pythonの正規表現を使用して文字列から特定箇所の抽出をしたい

Tags: python, 正規表現

Outlookのメール本文より必要な情報のみを抽出したいと考えております。
抽出したい部分に数字(最大で5桁の整数と少数第1位)と記号が混在していて現在数字のみ抽出できている状態です。
どちらにでも対応できるような正規表現の書き方をご教示いただけると幸いです。

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = """名前:\r\nsatou:\r\n前回の点数 : 14686.5 点\r\n今回の点数 : 8992.5 点\r\n\r\n名前:\r\ntanaka:\r\n前回の点数 : 778.5 点\r\n今回の点数 : 82.5 点\r\n\r\n名前:\r\nsuzuki:\r\n前回の点数 : - 点\r\n今回の点数 : 9.5 点\r\n\r\n"""

ptn = r"名前:\r\n(.*?):\r\n前回の点数\s:\s*([\d.]+)\s*点\r\n今回の点数\s:\s*([\d.]+)\s*(\w+)"
output_data = pd.DataFrame(re.findall(ptn, data, re.M | re.DOTALL))

output_data = output_data.rename(columns={0:"名前", 1:"前回の点数", 2:"今回の点数", 3:"単位"})
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True)

data = """名前:\r\nsatou:\r\n前回の点数 : 14686.5 点\r\n今回の点数 : 8992.5 点\r\n\r\n名前:\r\ntanaka:\r\n前回の点数 : 778.5 点\r\n今回の点数 : 82.5 点\r\n\r\n名前:\r\nsuzuki:\r\n前回の点数 : - 点\r\n今回の点数 : 9.5 点\r\n\r\n"""

output_data = (
    pd.DataFrame([
        m.groupdict() for m in re.finditer(
            r'名前:\r\n(?P<名前>.+?):\r\n'
            r'前回の点数\s:\s*(?P<前回の点数>.+?)\s*点\r\n'
            r'今回の点数\s:\s*(?P<今回の点数>.+?)\s*'
            r'(?P<単位>\w+)(?=\r\n)', data)]))

print(output_data)

#
     名前 前回の点数 今回の点数 単位
0   satou    14686.5     8992.5   点
1  tanaka      778.5       82.5   点
2  suzuki          -        9.5   点
```

Answer (score 0):

suzukiさんの「前回の点数 : - 点」を正規表現で抽出できないことが問題点でしたら、`([\d.]+)`を数字だけでなくマイナス記号に適合するよう書き換えることで対応可能です。

- 変更前

  - `点数\s:\s*([\d.]+)\s*`
- 変更例1

  - `点数\s:\s*([\d.]+|-)\s*`
    小数または - に適合します。ただし "1.2.3" などにもヒットします。
- 変更例2

  - `点数\s:\s*(\d{1,5}\.\d?|-)\s*点`
    1桁～5桁の整数 + 小数点以下1桁または - に適合します。整数のみの場合はヒットしません。
- 変更例3

  - `点数\s:\s*(\d{1,5}(?:\.\d)?|-)\s*点`
    1桁～5桁の整数 + 小数点以下1桁または - に適合します。整数のみの場合もヒットします。

Comment: payanecoさん
変更例3で対応できました。ありがとうございました。